# PGP keys storing

Tags: keystore, pgp

I have PGP key, something like that:

```
-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
Version: PGP Desktop 10.2.1 (Build 4461)

vfOJzKVE/+jNV/MHzXC3rhnHgrrSVNhFBzbTngpEqT+oNndEv6MCWK9Ar0pX7gzb
...
G+NqWmlNiwZmVgOW25mhbzekpi0kh9cHwsRrViw6
=eI9s
-----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
```

I have to use this key to decrypt some data. I have a question - how to store securely this key? I tried to store it into keystore, but without success.

```
keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Input not an X.509 certificate
```

I have two questions:

1. Is it impossible to store this key in keystore?
2. If it's impossible, where is a "good practice" place to store these keys?

Answer (score 2):

As your file starts with `PGP PUBLIC KEY`, it can be used to encrypt data, but not to decrypt it. For decryption you would need the corresponding private key.

PGP keys are best stored in a keyring and managed by a PGP toolkit. The most common open-source toolkit to handle PGP keys is [GnuPG](https://gnupg.org/).

The error that you got hints that the Java-API you are using is expecting an SSL-key, not a PGP key.